# What does "subject" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I don"t quite understand what "subject" means in this sentence. Can anybody explain it for me?
"Don't subject yourself to ridicule."

Answer (score 4):

in your sentence, "subject" has the meaning

> bring upon
>
> Don't subject yourself to ridicule.
>   *Don't bring ridicule upon yourself*

To be

> subjected to *something*

is to be brought under the influence of, effects of, or object of an action.

For your usage, it is often pronounced "sub-JECT" with the accent on the second syllable, not to be confused with "SUB-ject" which is the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: Does it mean "stand" or "accept", Peter?

Comment: Neither "stand" nor "accept", just that there is *something* effecting an influence. For example, if it's raining and you walk outside you will "subject" yourself to the rain (and get wet). Whether you "stand" for it or "accept" it is a different matter. Usually, you will not "subject" yourself  to *something* because the consequences are not acceptable to you (you don't want to get wet). By "subjecting" yourself to an action, you become the object of that action, you can "accept" or not accept the result of the action, but that's a different issue.

Comment: "Subjecting onself" is not the archetypical use: X subjects Y to Z means that X causes Y to be affected or influenced by Z.

Comment: *-ject* is a word element from Latin that means "throw", and *sub-* means "under".  So, don't "throw yourself under" ridicule.